# cocos2d-xでタブレットか携帯電話か判定する方法

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x v3.10で、タブレットか携帯電話か判定する方法が知りたいです。
以下のように、frameSizeの縦横比を調べて、それが1.5以上の場合はタブレットだと判断していました。
iOS端末の場合はこれで判定できました。

```
Size frameSize = glview->getFrameSize();

if (frameSize.width / frameSize.height >= 1.5f) {
    //phone
    glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize_phone.width,
                                    designResolutionSize_phone.height,
                                    ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
} else {
    //tablet
    glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize_tablet.width,
                                    designResolutionSize_tablet.height,
                                    ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
}
```

しかし、Android端末の場合、例えばNexut10の縦横比は1.6なので、携帯電話と判定されてしまいます。
端末の物理的な画面サイズが7インチ以上の場合はタブレットと判断したいのですが、どのように判定すれば良いでしょうか。
物理サイズの取得方法等ご存知でしたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cocos2dxは知りません。
しかし、androidのSDKにはその機能があるので、もしcocos2dxのAPIにそのような機能がなければ、Javaで呼び出す他にないでしょうね。
というわけで、以下にjavaでのやり方を説明します。

一応、参考にさせてもらったサイトも挙げておきます。

- [画面サイズを攻略して機種依存を吸収する](http://techbooster.org/android/hacks/16066/)
- [画面サイズ(ピクセル)をセンチメートルに変換するには](http://android-note.open-memo.net/sub/layout--convert-screen-pixels-to-cm.html)

例えば、以下のような感じで画面サイズを計算できます。

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(metrics);
        DisplayMetrics realMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getRealMetrics(realMetrics);
        TextView textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText(String.format("display %dx%d (%.1f inch).\nreal %dx%d (%.1f inch).",
                    metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels,
                    Math.sqrt(Math.pow(metrics.widthPixels / metrics.xdpi, 2.0) + Math.pow(metrics.heightPixels / metrics.ydpi, 2.0)),
                    realMetrics.widthPixels, realMetrics.heightPixels,
                    Math.sqrt(Math.pow(realMetrics.widthPixels / realMetrics.xdpi, 2.0) + Math.pow(realMetrics.heightPixels / realMetrics.ydpi, 2.0))));
    }
}
```

注意する点は、「Display#getMetrics」と「Display#getRealMetrics」という２つのメソッドが存在する点です。

違いは、前者はアプリケーションが使用している表示領域に対して、後者はナビゲーションバーも含む「本当の」ハードウェアの表示領域の情報を取得する点です。
つまり、いわゆるスペック表通りの数値を期待するならば、後者を使います。

しかし、「Display#getRealMetrics」はAPILevel17からの実装になっているので、それ以前のOS(android4.2より古い機種)では動作しません。
(上記のリンク先で書かれているように、隠されている可能性もありますから、強引に使用できるかもしれませんが)

上記の事を踏まえて、どちらを使用するかはご自身で決めてください。

(もしかして、ナビゲーションバーを非表示にした状態で「Display#getMetrics」を呼べば、「Display#getRealMetrics」と同じ結果になるかなぁ…)

余談ですが、「iphone ipad 判別」でググったら、iOSでの質問とは別の判別方法が出てきました。
そっちの方がいいのでは?と思いますが、いかがですかね。
まぁ、何で区別したいかの理由にもよりますので、最終的な判断はお任せします。